# Define variable in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can I define a variable within JSX?

I've tried it with the following code but it doesn't work.
No error is thrown, it just renders nothing.

```
const languages = {
  en: {
    language: "English"
  },
  de: {
    language: "Deutsch"
  }
}
```

```
{() => {
  const { language: name } = languages[language]
  return (
    <>
      {name}
    </>
  )
}}
```

Comment: Can you share your languages array example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just defining the `function` but never calling it. Either execute it immediately after declaration `function(){return jsx}()` but the most common practice is to declare it outside `jsx`'s block

```
const renderItems = items => items.map(x => <Item key={x} />)

return <div>{renderItems()}</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you every render such component? Possible implementation of your component which should work is:

```
const languages = {
  en: {
    language: "English"
  },
  de: {
    language: "Deutsch"
  }
}

const LanguageComponent = ({language}) => {
  const { language: name } = languages[language]
  return (
    <>
      {name}
    </>
  )
}


Usage:
<LanguageComponent language='en' />
```

Answer (score 3):

You defined a function but did not call it, that's why it renders nothing :

`{ () => {/* your code */} }`

You can call the function inline like this :

`{ (() => {/* your code */})() }`

Or define it outside the render method for more readability